# Centering usercontrol in panel with anchor removes scrollbar?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel, anchor

In my current project I have a problem when I add my `usercontrol` into the `panel` of `splitcontainer`. I managed to add it to the middle of the panel with the following code:

```
        ucFactuur ucFactuur = new ucFactuur();

        ucFactuur.Location = new Point(
           splitContainer1.Panel2.ClientSize.Width / 2 - ucFactuur.Size.Width / 2,
           splitContainer1.Panel2.ClientSize.Height / 2 - ucFactuur.Size.Height / 2);
        ucFactuur.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(ucFactuur);
```

But now my scrollbar is gone, it is there when I remove the `AnchorStyles.None` but then when I resize the window it doesn't stay in the middle (It's in a fixed position).

[image: No Scrollbar]

I'm uncertain how to resolve this problem, nor can I find any other way to dynamically center my usercontrol.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Anchoring.None` won't work in this situation since it only works when there are no scrollbars.  But once you have scrollbars, you don't want the control centered anymore, you need it positioned against the scroll value.

In other words, I think you have to handle the resizing yourself:

```
private void DoResize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollMinSize = ucFactuur.Size;

  if (ucFactuur.Width < splitContainer1.Panel2.ClientSize.Width) {
    ucFactuur.Left = splitContainer1.Panel2.ClientSize.Width / 2 -
                     ucFactuur.Width / 2;
  } else {
    ucFactuur.Left = splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition.X;
  }

  if (ucFactuur.Height < splitContainer1.Panel2.ClientSize.Height) {
    ucFactuur.Top = splitContainer1.Panel2.ClientSize.Height / 2 -
                    ucFactuur.Height / 2;
  } else {
    ucFactuur.Top = splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScrollPosition.Y;
  }
}
```

Then your setup would change to this:

```
ucFactuur ucFactuur = new ucFactuur();
ucFactuur.AutoSize = true;
ucFactuur.Resize += DoResize;
splitContainer1.Panel2.Resize += DoResize;
splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScroll = false;
splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(ucFactuur);
```

Comment: @ThomasSchoof I can only go by the code you posted.  I used a panel in place of `ucFactuur` and in my example, I got scrollbars on Panel2.

Comment: My ucFactuur is a normal userControl that is set to AutoSize because the size of it can increase. I have put the designer code on this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/khHqADNz

Comment: @ThomasSchoof I fixed the answer.  Because of the resizing, anchoring won't work.  You will have to handle the positioning of the child control based on resizing events.

Comment: The method DoResize doesn't know ucFactuur, is there any way to fix this besides creating the UserControl in Runtime?
I also have more than one UserContol that I add to my panel, so I would have to create separate methods for each one? 
Thanks a lot for the help! :D

Comment: @ThomasSchoof If you are adding multiple controls into the panel, you might have to enumerate through the `Panel2.Controls` collection instead.  Sounds like a complicated UI.

Comment: It's not very complicated, all I am doing is adding a UserControl to my panel when you press a button (to get different pages). Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: @ThomasSchoof OK, I get it.  You can try holding a class variable `Control uc` and use that in your resize event.  When you load your `ucFactuur` or other "user control", just change the reference: `uc = ucFactuur;`.  Add an `if (uc != null) {}` to the resize procedure.